# Why doesn't browser re-render when controller updates?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

For some reason when a member variable of my controller gets changed, which is linked to in my HTML, the browser re-render to show the new variable until I type in a input box on the same page. I'd of expected

> {{SignInCtrl.userLoggedIn}}

to get updated automatically when `bool userLoggedIn` is changed.

Controller

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
import 'dart:html'; //for window.console


@NgController(
    selector: '[signin-controller]',
    publishAs: 'SignInCtrl')
class SignInController {
  bool userLoggedIn = false;
```

HTML

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html><html ng-app>
<head><meta charset='UTF-8'>



        <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.dev.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <style>.ng-hide{
            display: none !important;
        }
        .ng-show {

        }

            #auth {
            border: none;
        }

    @media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
        #auth button {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }</style></head><body>

<main ng-cloak signin-controller>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" ng-controller="SignInCtrl">
       <span>
      Is user logged in: {{SignInCtrl.userLoggedIn}}
    </span>

    </nav>


</main>

<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@MirrorsUsed(override: '*') //used to make js output files smaller
import 'dart:mirrors';

import 'package:my_app/app_module.dart';

void main() {
  ngBootstrap(module: new AppModule());
}
```

Comment: Can you try if it updates when you resize the browser windows a bit?
I think there was a bug in Dartium. Can you try if this is also when you built to JavaScript.
Could also have to do with the new change detection but I have no experience with this yet.

Comment: If I resize the browser window it doesn't re-render. I built into JavaScript and it doesn't seem to re-render at all, even when I type into a input box

Comment: The you should try to use a filter like `{{SignInCtrl.userLoggedIn | filter}}` (but they were renamed and I have no current name at hand) You could also try `{{SignInCtrl.userLoggedIn.toString()}}`

Comment: Tried '{{SignInCtrl.userLoggedIn.toString()}}` but didn't change anything.

Comment: I've cleaned up my code a bit and it now functions identically in javascript except I get an error which doesn't occur in dart. Not sure if its relevant: `Uncaught Illegal argument(s): "class" is not a valid (qualified) symbol name`

Comment: I think you should file an issue in the AngularDart Github repo.